# How to get the current MAC address and pass it to a variable in the Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I found a command from another post on Super User that’s helped me, but I don’t know how to pass the output to a variable and print it.

This is the command I've used:

```
ip addr show $(awk 'NR==3{print $1}' /proc/net/wireless | tr -d :) | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
```

My complete script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Diconnect the network
nmcli d disconnect wlan0

# Down interface
ifconfig wlan0 down

# Randomize my mac address
macchanger -r wlan0

# Up interface
ifconfig wlan0 up

# Connect network again
nmcli d connect wlan0

# Get current mac generated by 'macchanger'
ip addr show $(awk 'NR==3{print $1}' /proc/net/wireless | tr -d :) | awk '/ether/{print $2}'

# Open the web page using current mac generated
xdg-open "http://webapplication.com/?mac=MY_MAC_ADDRES"
```

Comment: Looking at `macchanger`, it should already echo the MAC address it set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should find the MAC for `eth0`. You may have to change that interface (`eth0`) to match your setup needs but it should work.

```
DETECTED_MAC_ADDRESS=`ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null|awk '/HWaddr/ {print $5}'`
```

Comment: Just had to copy it out of one of my scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the mac address of all your network devices via the `/sys/devices` file system.

This will find all of the mac addresses of the network devices on the pci bus.  The MAC address is stored in the file `address`.

```
sudo find /sys/devices -wholename */pci*/net/*/address -exec cat {} +
```

output:

```
00:XX:XX:XX:XX:83
00:XX:XX:XX:XX:82
```